# Spring boot MongoRepository query to match default query if main query does not match

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongorepository

I've a collection in which I have multiple records, as below,

| Name | age |
| --- | --- |
| Abcd | 100 |
| pqrs | 200 |
| none | 000 |

User will give the name, and my method will fetch data and return age, fetching based on "Name", as below,

```
res = mongoRepository.findByName(userName);
```

but I want to fetch data for Name "none" if the name provided by user is not present in collection. So currently I'm doing as below,

```
res = mongoRepository.findByName(userName);

if (res1 == null){
   res = mongoRepository.findByName("none");
}
```

But is there any way to do this in single call ?

Please note, I can not hardcode data for "none" in code, I must fetch it from DB.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could use '$or' within the query executed by `findByName`, and filter the 'none' entry out if multiple documents are returned.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Joe If there's no way to do something like switch-case-default thing in MongoRepository, I think I will go with your suggestion.